# Root Xperia Arc S

Tags: rooting

Root to phone is harmful or not?
I've XperiaArcS & some files of it I want to transfer in Sdcard but it require RootHelp. So please give me advice what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

to root or not to root is an individual preference and largely based upon skill.  that being said i always have preferred to take the easy, reliable way out.  first download and install clockworkmod from the play store - google your device and android version to find out how to access the menu without using the app from the ui at first, usually some combo of power, the up volume key, and the home key.  make a backup using cwm, very first thing you should do in case of fu.  next go on a pc browser and dl this app --  http://www.kingoapp.com/

you should install it and then open it and it will create a dialogue box on your desktop.  at that point plug your device into your pc using it's usb cord.  when that is done and the drivers are installed if they haven't previously been so hit the blue "root" button and watch.  about 5 minutes later your device has root, unplug the device from the pc, and close kingoapp.  all done.